# SQL Unique rows

Tags: sql-server

Data before Output

[image: Data before Output]

New to SQL. In the data, I need an SQL query that will return rows in a way that if `Init is not null`, then return the max of `Att Date` by month, otherwise it should just return the date. So, the output for the above example needs to be as below.

Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

use `group by`

```
select ID, FORMAT(AsgnDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-us') AsgnDate
,FORMAT(AttDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-us') AttDate , 
case when max(INIT) is null then '' else max(INIT) end as INIT from t
group by ID, AsgnDate,AttDate
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a1f8/9

```
ID  AsgnDate    AttDate INIT
1   01/05/2018  22/05/2018  ABC
1   01/05/2018  28/06/2018  
1   01/05/2018  10/07/2018  
2   01/05/2018  09/05/2018  DEF
2   01/05/2018  25/07/2018
```